# React Filtering Data with Hooks

Tags: arrays, reactjs, filter

I'm working with a dataset and want to implement a filtering option to only display what is selected (as filters do :) ). Here's the data and my code so far:

```js
// Movies data = 
[
 {
   name: "a",
   genre: "comedy",
   year: "2019",
 },
 {
   name: "b",
   genre: "drama",
   year: "2019",
 },
 {
   name: "c",
   genre: "suspense",
   year: "2020",
 },
 {
   name: "d",
   genre: "comedy",
   year: "2020",
 },
 {
   name: "e",
   genre: "drama",
   year: "2021",
 },
 {
   name: "f",
   genre: "action",
   year: "2021",
 },
 {
   name: "g",
   genre: "action",
   year: "2022",
 },
]
```

and in my code, I'm have a piece of state for the API response (all data) as well as filtered data per year

```js
import { useEffect, useState, useMemo } from 'react';

const MovieData = () => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]); // all data. This will not change after API call
  const [results setResults] = useState([]); // this will change based on selection
  const [year, setYear] = useState({
    y2019: false,
    y2020: false,
    y2021: false
  });

  // making API call
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("myapiep")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => setMovies(data))
  }, []);

  // get subsets of data
  const {m2019, m2020, m2021} = useMemo(() => {
    const m2019 = movies.filter(m => m.year === '2019');
    const m2020 = movies.filter(m => m.year === '2020');
    const m2021 = movies.filter(m => m.year === '2021');

    return {m2019, m2020, m2021}
  });

  // So far so good. Now this is where things get tricky for me
  // I want to, based on the selection, modify my results array
  useEffect(() => {
    // update results based on movie year selected
    if (year.y2019) setResults([...results, ...m2019]);
    // HELP: filter out results when year is unselected
    // this is not working
    else {
      const newArr = results.filter((movie) => !m2019.includes(movie));
    }
    if (year.y2020) setResults([...results, ...m2020]);
    else {
      const newArr = results.filter((movie) => !m2020.includes(movie));
    }
    if (year.y2021) setResults([...results, ...m2021]);
    else {
      const newArr = results.filter((movie) => !m2021.includes(movie));
    }
    // if none are selected, just return all movies
    if (!year.y2019 && !year.y2020 && !year.y2021) {
      setResults(movies);
    } 
  }, [year]);

  // I'm suppressing the logic to toggle years (y20xx) true/false for simplicity, but can add it if folks judge necessary

  return (
    <div>
      {results.map((movie) => (
          <Movie
            key={uuidv4()}
            name={movie.name}
            genre={movie.genre}
            year={movie.year}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
  )
}
```

What works: set filter works, for instance, setting the filter to movies made in 2019 returns

```js
[
 {
   name: "a",
   genre: "comedy",
   year: "2019",
 },
 {
   name: "b",
   genre: "drama",
   year: "2019",
 },
]
```

What doesn't: unset the filter.

Comment: What's not working exactly? Expect/actual output is helpful. I also suggest removing the request for general remarks -- it's off-topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The below code snippet achieves the necessary logic (sans the React Hooks, API, and other items):

```js
const movies = [{
    name: "a",
    genre: "comedy",
    year: "2019",
  },
  {
    name: "b",
    genre: "drama",
    year: "2019",
  },
  {
    name: "c",
    genre: "suspense",
    year: "2020",
  },
  {
    name: "d",
    genre: "comedy",
    year: "2020",
  },
  {
    name: "e",
    genre: "drama",
    year: "2021",
  },
  {
    name: "f",
    genre: "action",
    year: "2021",
  },
  {
    name: "g",
    genre: "action",
    year: "2022",
  }
];

const filterMyMovies = (byField = 'year', value = '2020', myMovies = movies) => (
  (myMovies || [])
  .filter(mov => !byField || !mov[byField] || mov[byField] === value)
);

console.log('movies in year 2020:\n', filterMyMovies());
console.log('movies in year 2019:\n', filterMyMovies('year', '2019'));
console.log('movies in genre drama:\n', filterMyMovies('genre', 'drama'));
console.log('movies with name d:\n', filterMyMovies('name', 'd'));
console.log('movies with NO FILTER:\n', filterMyMovies(null, null));
```

**Explanation**
Fairly-straightforward filtering of an array of objects, with only 1 column & 1 value. May be improvised for multi-column & multi-value filtering.

**How to use this**
The way to use this within React-Hooks is to invoke the 'filterMyMovies' method with the appropriate parameters when the filter-criteria changes. Suppose, the year is set to 'no-filter', then simply make call to the 'filterMyMovies' method  with the first & second params as null.

Suppose we need to filter by year and then by genre as well, try something like this:

```
filterMyMovies('genre', 'comedy', filterMyMovies('year', '2019'));
```

This will return 2019 comedy movies.